# How to authenticate between EC2 and SQS and local machine to SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to authenticate with SQS on my local machine **and** on an EC2 instance. On my local machine I can successfully use a profile:

```
ProfileCredentialsProvider p = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName("my-profile").build();
```

However, I'm not sure what I need to do to authenticate from the EC2, do I need to add an IAM role and give the EC2 permissions to SQS  (I'm quite new to AWS Auth)?

I thought I could use `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` for the EC2 but that didn't work but that could be because I'm missing the Role permission step above?

```
SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().credentialsProvider(p)
            .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
            .build();
```

---

I'm guessing but I think the final result will be:

```
ProfileCredentialsProvider p = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName("my-profile").build();
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider i = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().build();
        
sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
                    .credentialsProvider(p)
                    .credentialsProvider(i)
                    .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                    .build();
```

I'm using the aws SDK Version 2 `software.amazon.awssdk:sqs:2.17.24`

Comment: (1) What exception you are getting for code using EC2 InstanceProfile? it should work if you are setting/using right profile in code with all required permissions (2) Have you checked https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-sending-messages-from-vpc.html alternate way?

Comment: @amitd software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EC2 the preferred method is to assign an IAM role to the instance that has the required SQS permissions.

I suggest reading how the [default credential provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) works. As long as you provide one of the credential methods the default credential provider looks for, you don't have to do anything special in your code to use those credentials.

For example when your code is running on EC2 it can automatically pick up the IAM role assigned to the instance, and your code can look like this:

```
sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().build();
```

Note that no credentials providers are passed to the client. Also it will use the same region the EC2 instance is running in by default, so you don't need to pass the region either.

---

For running locally you can simply set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable before running your code.

Comment: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443

Comment: This is the error I receive from within the EC2. During queue creation, I gave the queue account access by giving my account id. Do I need to do more?

Comment: That's a network error, not a permissions/credentials issue. Does the EC2 instance have a public IP address? If not, does it have a route to a NAT gateway in the subnet it is running in, or a route to a SQS Private Link?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it - a network issue.